# Connecting HTML to MYSQL Through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm working on a website but I'm a little unsure how to proceed. I've read through some documentation but I think I'm missing something or looking into the wrong stuff. Basically, I have a website with a bunch of pages and a few pages that have forms. I'm trying to tackle my first form, register, which contains a register form. Here is the form that the user will fill out to register:

```
<form action = "register.php" method = "post">

  <br><br>First Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  Street Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="streetaddress"> <br>
  City:<br>
  <input type="text" name="city"> <br>
  State:<br>
  <input type="text" name="state"> <br>
  Zip Code:<br>
  <input type="text" name="zipcode"> <br>
  Phone Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="phonenumber"> <br>
  Email Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="emailaddress"> <br>
  User Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password"> <br>

  <br>Would you like to receive emails about CSIT World Conference?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="email" value="yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="email" value="no">No

  <br><br>Would you be interested in volunteering at CSIT World Conference??<br>
  <input type="radio" name="help" value="yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="help" value="no">No

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I thought it should then send the data to register.php which looks like this.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'register');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_NAME, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
     $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
     $streetaddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
     $city = $_POST['city'];
     $state = $_POST['state'];
     $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
     $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
     $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, streetaddress, city, state, zipcode, phonenumber, emailaddress, username, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$phonenumber', '$emailaddress', '$username', '$password')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();


</script>

</html>
```

I also created an empty MYSQL database through phpmyadmin on XAMPP. Basically I'm trying to figure out if I'm on the right track. My understanding is that once I hit submit, it should populate the register.mysql table I created. However, nothing seems to be happening.

Also, here is my connect.php file

```
<html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");    
        if(!$con){

        die("Cannot connect:".mysql_error());
        }   


        mysql_close($con);  

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to read the manual on `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: `mysql_connect(DB_NAME, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)` which is incorrect. So, why do you have that if you have a connect file?

Comment: So I don't need that if I have a connect file? For some reason I thought that was always required. So I will delete the file?

Comment: exactly. Just do this `$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);` and keep the rest of your code and you should be ok. But that code is old and hope you don't intend on going live with this for many reasons.

Comment: No this is for educational purposes. Definitely will not be a real website

Comment: I've no idea why you have that stray `</script>` tag in there. Besides that, working now?

Comment: Yeah It doesn't seem to return an error. I tried the code below and that gave me other errors. So assuming I keep this older format, how do I find the data then? Shouldn't I be able to view it in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. It's better to try to learn PDO but for this example you can use mysqli_*. Also, check about hashing passwords. I hope you find the following code useful.

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'register');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
if (!$link) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
//Use array to not repeat code
$post_vars = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'streetaddress', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'phonenumber', 'emailaddress', 'username', 'password');
foreach($post_vars as $key) {
    $$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[$key]);
    //For example now there is a variable $firstname that you can use
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, streetaddress, city, state, zipcode, phonenumber, emailaddress, username, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$phonenumber', '$emailaddress', '$username', '$password');";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Edit:

You can select your data like this (consider also trying the PDO code that the other answer has).

```
$query = "SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM user;";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['username'].'<br />';
}
```

EDIT 2

The SQL for user table is the following. Edit it accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(40),
    lastname varchar(40),
    username varchar(40),
    password varchar(40),
    state varchar(40),
    city varchar(40),
    streetaddress varchar(40),
    zipcode varchar(40),
    phonenumber varchar(40),
    emailaddress varchar(255),
    email tinyint unsigned default 1,
    help tinyint unsigned default 1,
    time_created timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Getting these errors when I submit the form:

Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\Louis-Colucci-Proj-1-1\register.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Louis-Colucci-Proj-1-1\register.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Louis-Colucci-Proj-1-1\register.php on line 25

Comment: OK great, no errors returned. Thank you much! But my next trouble is how do I pull this data? Shouldn't I be able to find it in PHPMyAdmin? I am going to be creating a login page next using this data so shouldnt it be visible somewhere?

Comment: Check at the table "register".

Comment: I guess what has me confused is, do I have to create something in PHPmyAdmin? I made a database in there called "register" but do I have to create tables and such for the data? Can't the PHP script auto create the tables once the database is made?

Comment: Oh, then in your "register" database you have to create a table lets say "user" with all these columns. I ''ll edit my answer so you have the right queries.

Comment: Oh ok, so each line of the form is considered a new column? I still have to add the 2 radio buttons so this form will have a table with 10 (text fields) + 2(radio buttons) 12 total columns.

Comment: Yes, you can add those two columns.

Comment: Ok awesome. I think I have it figured out. I created a table with 10 values as type "TEXT". Now I Just need to add in the radio buttons as type "BOOL" i'm guessing. I really appreciate your help. My next goal is to figure out the login screen

Comment: Try not to use type "text" if you are really don't need it. See here about storage requirements about each type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Any idea why it's posting data from the radio buttons nor updating the table anymore? I added another user and tried to register it but nothing is updated. I posted my updated code at top.

Comment: In your insert query $'email', should be '$email' and $'help' is '$help' Also what name has the table you created because 'register' is the database name. Better name the table as 'user' or something like this.

Comment: Really appreciate your help by the way. I made the change to the quote and renamed the table to user. However, I'm trying to register a second user and the table is not adding the second person. By the way, I just saw your code for the user table. Where would I put that? Right in my folder with the html and php files but name it user.msql?

Comment: Be sure you have changed $'help' to '$help' and also that the query inserts into 'user' table like: INSERT INTO user

Comment: No, this sql code is to create the user table. phpMyAdmin has a tab named 'SQL' that you can copy and paste that code and create the table. Drop the table you have created and make a new one using the above code.

Comment: Ahh that was it, didn't update the INSERT INTO. Last couple of questions if you don't mind and then I think I can build from here-- again I appreciate it. Am I handling the radio buttons wrong? I selected boolean as the datatype when I made the table but no matter what it keeps the value as 0, whether I check yes or no. If I use the actual code you gave me where would I place it for this table, in the project folder?

Comment: Which are the table columns that will store the radio button values?

Comment: For radio buttons i would give different values e.g.:  <input type="radio" name="email" value="1">Yes  <input type="radio" name="email" value="2">No

Comment: Also i would had in database type as: help tinyint unsigned

Comment: The type is set to "tinyint. Do you know where I can go to export my mysql code? I only see the gui through phpmyadim

Comment: You click at the database name and then on the tab "Export".

Comment: Ok I added my exported mysql code to my main post.

Comment: Nice. I edited my answer providing the sql you should use. Drop your table and create it using the sql above.

Comment: I need to go to bed. Would you be ok with it if i emailed (what's your email please) you at some point tomorrow for a little more help? I'm going to build as much of it as I can from here though. I really appreciate all your assistance.

Comment: Yes, sure. It's kostmits@yahoo.gr

Comment: Done. I marked it as accepted and and I upvoted you. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Thank you very much. See u tomorrow.

Comment: `password varchar(40),` that is way too short a value for a password column. If and when the OP decides to use `password_hash()`, he will have to ALTER that column to 60. The manual suggests 255 http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: You are right about hashing but for the particular case i considered that it would be overkill because OP is a beginner and he is already struggling to achieve some basic staff. But if you think that i was wrong please inform me so i can provide better answers next time.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis I didn't say you were "wrong", I had to make a mention of that and for future readers to the question ;-)

Comment: Oh, i wouldn't had any problem even if you told me that i made a mistake. I am new in SO so i just try to find the right way to write better answers and you obviously have more experience so for that reason i asked if i was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise the same! use PDO and make sure you "PREPARE" your statements, I've re-written your data using PDO. By preparing our data we can prevent SQL injection which could have adverse affects on your data integrity as well as give unwanted users access to your tables.

```
 <?php

// config

$dbtype     = "mysql";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "register";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "password";

// Connection Info

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);



// Write Query

$sql = "INSERT INTO books (firstname,lastname,streetaddress,city,state,zipcode,phonenumber,emailaddress,username,password) VALUES (firstname,:lastname,:streetaddress,:city,:state,:zipcode,:phonenumber,:emailaddress,:username,:password)";

// Prepare Statement


$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname
':lastname'=>$lastname
':streetaddress'=>$streetaddress
':city'=>$city 
':state'=>$state  
':zipcode'=>$zipcode  
':phonenumber'=>$phonenumber  
':emailaddress'=>$emailaddress  
':username'=>$username 
':password'=>$password));


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to try rebuilding the assignment with this approach as well.

Comment: Sounds good let me know how it goes or if you need help , I'll be around most of the day.

Comment: This will fail for 2 reasons. 1) Missing a colon in the first values array, and the missing commas for the execute array. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: That is not my downvote btw.